# How to find which user is using a port in Java

Tags: java, web-applications, localhost, port

I'd like to map a port number to a user (linux user that is running a process that is binding to the port).
How can I do it in java?

I know I can go out to the shell and run bash commands that map a port to a PID, and then PID to user, but I'd like to keep it inside java if I can.

The more general question is: I have a webapp application that receives requests from localhost, and I'd like to know which local user performed the HttpServletRequest, so I can attach proper authorities to it.

#### Background:

I'm using spring security for all remote connections. However, I have a small part of the application (separated from the webapp) that is running locally alongside the application server, and that application is authenticated using the linux user mechanism. So for that reason, I bypass the server authentication rules for localhost (assuming all localhost access is permitted). The problem is with authorization - I need the identify the user running the localhost requests. Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is Linux dependent code, but not difficult to port to Windows.

This is not a Servlet code, but would work in that case as well:

Lets say I've a ServerSocket waiting on accept() call. When it receives a client request, it creates a Socket at another port to deal with that 'remote' request.

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2000);
System.out.println("Listening on local port : " + ss.getLocalPort());

while(...)
{
 Socket s = ss.accept();
 System.out.println("accepted client request, opened local port : " + s.getPort());
 ...
}
```

So, you need to feed the output of s.getPort() from above snippet to the following program's main() method.

```
public class FindUserByPort
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    String cmd = "netstat -anp | grep ";
    int port = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
    cmd = cmd + port ;

    Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    InputStream is = pr.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = null;
    List<Integer> pIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
      if (line.contains("127.0.0.1:" + port))
      {
        String pidPname = line.substring(line.indexOf("ESTABLISHED") + "ESTABLISHED".length());
        pidPname = pidPname.trim();
        String pid = pidPname.split("/")[0];
        pIDs.add(Integer.valueOf(pid));
      }
    }
    if (pIDs.size() > 0)
    {
      for (int pid : pIDs)
      {
        String command = "top -n1 -b -p " + pid ;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        InputStream _is = p.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader _br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_is));
        String _line = null;
        while ((_line = _br.readLine()) != null)
        {
          _line = _line.trim();
          if(_line.startsWith(String.valueOf(pid)))
          {
            String[] values = _line.split(" ");
            System.out.println("pid : " + pid + ", user : " + values[1]);
          }
        }
        _is.close();
        _br.close();
      }
    }
    is.close();
    br.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your above code,It looks interesting but its gone above my head.just explain the above code